# Is it ok to make std::once_flag a member (non static member)

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to make some calculations and cache results for current object lazily (upon first request). I can do it with mutex obviously, but I am just curios is it ok to make `std::once_flag` a member and use it to initialize this instance. I used it for singletons but not for ordinary objects.

Comment: What do you think is magical about `once_flag` that means it can't be a member variable? It's just neither copyable nor movable, so if you don't need to copy/move your object and having the flag as a member is convenient...

Comment: I don't know how it implemented. I am afraid of running some performance issues if I make a lot them

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly *possible* to do what you suggest. Provided the `once_flag` is properly constructed before attempting to use it<sup>(a)</sup>, it should work fine, and that can be guaranteed simply by having it as a member variable within the class, something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass() {
            std::cout << "Constructing\n";
        }
        void DoSomething() {
            std::call_once(m_lazyInit, []() {
                std::cout << "Lazy init\n";
            });
            std::cout << "Doing something\n";
        }
    private:
        std::once_flag m_lazyInit;
};

int main() {
    MyClass x;
    x.DoSomething(); // Sequential but would also work concurrently.
    x.DoSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

At any point after that, only one successful call to the lazy initialisation code will be made for your object regardless of how many times you call `DoSomething()`:

```
Constructing
Lazy init
Doing something
Doing something
```

---

It *seems* that, from your comments, you're concerned it will be resource heavy and it may be *less* strenuous to use something like a static (class-level) mutex with a member boolean to do the same thing. That way, the possible-heavy-load threading stuff is limited to one item rather than one item per object (replacing just the class in the above code):

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() : m_lazyInitFlag(true) {
        std::cout << "Constructing\n";
    }
    void DoSomething() {
        {   // Limit lock duration to as short as possible.
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lazyInit(m_lazyInitMutex);
            if (m_lazyInitFlag) {
                std::cout << "Lazy init\n";
                m_lazyInitFlag = false;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Doing something\n";
    }
private:
    static std::mutex m_lazyInitMutex;
    bool m_lazyInitFlag;
};
std::mutex MyClass::m_lazyInitMutex;
```

---

However, I'd be *less* concerned about that. The people putting together your standard library will have optimised it to the maximum extent possible and will have almost certainly considered the possibility that you need per-object `call-once()` callables.

In addition, a solution like that static-mutex-member-flag option introduces *more* contention since you can only run one concurrent callable across the entire class rather then one in each object.

It's also going to mean that, should you wish to use callables that can fail, you'll need to handle that yourself with `try..catch` blocks rather than get the automatic handling provided by `call_once()`.

My advice would be to just use the `call_once()` functionality since that really *is* its intended use case. Only worry about possible performance problems when they appear and, at that point, you can investigate other solutions.

In other words, YAGNI :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> As Barry points out in a comment, you'll also have a restriction on copying or moving your object since the non-copyable, non-movable `once_flag` member will prevent this.

So, if you *need* to copy or move your objects, you may want to use another option.